# Ffmpeg Command to capture video from Decklink 4k Extreme in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-capture

I am trying to capture a video using ffmpeg, from the HDMI input port of the Blackmagic DeckLink 4K Extreme capture card in Ubuntu Linux.

As per the [ffmpeg Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#decklink) I have tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -f decklink -video_input 'hdmi' -i 'DeckLink 4K Extreme (1)@14' -acodec copy -vcodec copy ~/testCapture/card1_f14_hdmi.avi
```

but no matter what I do I always get this picture as a video
[image: Video unavailable]

My ffmpeg version is :

> ```
> ffmpeg version git-2016-08-15-4899953 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
> configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static 
> --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include 
> --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib 
> --bindir=/root/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac 
> --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora 
> --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 
> --enable-decklink 
> --extra-cflags=-I/root/decklinkSDK/Blackmagic_DeckLink_SDK/Linux/include
> --extra-ldflags=-L/root/decklinkSDK/Blackmagic_DeckLink_SDK/Linux/include
> --enable-nonfree
> libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
> libavcodec     57. 51.102 / 57. 51.102
> libavformat    57. 46.101 / 57. 46.101
> libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
> libavfilter     6. 51.100 /  6. 51.100
> libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
> libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
> libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
> ```

I have two of these cards as per the following:

> ```
> ffmpeg -f decklink -list_devices 1 -i dummy
> .....
> [decklink @ 0x2e9e440] Blackmagic DeckLink devices:
> [decklink @ 0x2e9e440]    'DeckLink 4K Extreme (1)'
> [decklink @ 0x2e9e440]    'DeckLink 4K Extreme (2)'
> ```

I am able to get a list of the supported formats with the following:

> ```
> ffmpeg -f decklink -list_formats 1 -i 'DeckLink 4K Extreme (1)'
> ...
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440] Supported formats for 'DeckLink 4K Extreme (1)':
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    1   720x486 at 30000/1001 fps (interlaced, lower field first)
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    2   720x576 at 25000/1000 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    3   1920x1080 at 24000/1001 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    4   1920x1080 at 24000/1000 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    5   1920x1080 at 25000/1000 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    6   1920x1080 at 30000/1001 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    7   1920x1080 at 30000/1000 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    8   1920x1080 at 25000/1000 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    9   1920x1080 at 30000/1001 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    10  1920x1080 at 30000/1000 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    11  1920x1080 at 50000/1000 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    12  1920x1080 at 60000/1001 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    13  1920x1080 at 60000/1000 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    14  1280x720 at 50000/1000 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    15  1280x720 at 60000/1001 fps
> [decklink @ 0x36e2440]    16  1280x720 at 60000/1000 fps
> ...
> DeckLink 4K Extreme (1): Immediate exit requested
> ```

What should I use with ffmpeg in order to capture an HD video with sound from the HDMI port?

Comment: BM is picky about input formats and sample formats. I have the exact issue and have verified with USB sdi capture card, that my SDI source is valid. I get the same bars capture when I use a port with no SDI connected.

Answer (score 2):

"Bars are displayed when the resolution / scan rate selected by the arguments set in ffmpeg does not match the input. You are currently setting it to 1280x720@50p"

from https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=50941

Bars are generated internally to the card. So my guess is confirm your HDMI is actually transmitting 720p50. That said, the "DeckLink Quad 2" supports many more formats and I get bars as well.

https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9654

uses a tool call `bmdcapture` from https://github.com/lu-zero/bmdtools which could be used in compliment with FFMPEG or libav.